# eclipse "potential resource leak" warning not correct

Tags: java, eclipse, memory-leaks

eclipse "potential resource leak" warning is not correct.

no warning:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(createSSLConnSocketFactory()).setConnectionManager(connMgr).setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
String apiUrl = ...;
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(apiUrl);
CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
HttpEntity entity;
try {
    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        logger.warn("invoke failed, response status={},key={}",statusCode,key);
        httpPost.close();
        if (response != null) {
             response.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

warning:potential resource leak: "response may not be closed at this location"

```
  CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(createSSLConnSocketFactory()).setConnectionManager(connMgr).setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
    String apiUrl = ...;
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(apiUrl);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
    HttpEntity entity;
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            logger.warn("invoke failed, response status={},key={}",statusCode,key);
            closeBoth(httpClient, response)
            return null;
        }
   }

private void closeBoth(CloseableHttpClient  client, CloseableHttpResponse  resp) {
  org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.closeQuitely(client);
  org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.closeQuitely(resp);
}
```

why the second approach cause warning?

Thanks!

Comment: How would eclipse know that `closeBoth` always closes `httpClient` and `response`?

Comment: Why not use try-with-resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse close warning code only looks at the current method. It does not analyze the `closeBoth` method to see what it does (and in this case it would also have to look at `closeQuitely` as well).

Comment: To op: also, take it for what it is: a warning. It's purpose is to help you. If the warning sign on the class icon annoys you, you can add `@SuppressWarning("resource")` above the marked line.